# How can I compute a SHA-256 hash in Progress 9.1 other than writing the algorithm myself?

Tags: sha256, progress-4gl

I am currently updating our payroll system (written in progress) to implement RTI. RTI requires a SHA-256 Hash to be created for linking the BACS payment to the RTI submission for each record. There is a SHA-1 object i can call in OE10 which does the job (only SHA1 though). I realize that SHA-256 is implemented in the latest release of OE 11 but some of our clients do not have or do not want to upgrade to OE11. Currently i use an old JAR routine to generate a SHA1 hash for the sending of p45/46 etc via the Government portal. I would like to stop using java and therefore would like to implement this in progress

Any advice/pointers much appreciated

Kind Regards

Craig H

Answer (score 0):

Progress version 9 was designed and released in the late 1990s.  This kind of functionality was not on the radar back then and v9 is now retired -- so no more releases.

OpenEdge 10 is much newer, is a simple upgrade, and supports SHA-256 out of the box.  I suggest that you upgrade.